# Problems with Directory Services and Account Management in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx, directoryservices

I have a ASP.NET Core API project and I'd like to utilize DirectoryServices and DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespaces.

After some research I thought I found some project.json references that would work:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.DirectoryServices": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { },
    "net451": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

After adding those, code that used classes from those references suggested the namespaces to add to the class:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

After that intellisense had no complaints and everything looked perfect, however if I try to build or run the project I get "type or namespace name 'DirectoryServices' does not exist in the namespace 'System'" errors.

Is there a resource out there can help me figure out how to implement DirectoryServices and DirectoryServices.AccountManagement in ASP.Net 5?

As a side note I like ASP.NET Core but it seems like having to manually create a json file for references is a big step back from adding references in MVC 5 where you just had to find them and check the box to add them.  Makes me wonder if there isn't something I'm missing that can generate that file for you rather than needing to know the exact characters and pasting them in yourself to get things working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core (the new Name for ASP.NET 5 and vNext isn't being officially used for months) a project will by default target multiple platforms.

You have added the references to `dnx451` framework moniker, which targets the full .NET 4.5 Framework.

Now if you use

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

inside a *.cs file, it will work for .NET 4.5, but fail for .NET Core, because there is no reference for .NET Core to this namespaces/assemblies. On build always both versions will be compiled, that's why you get this error.

You don't see it in the Visual Studio Editor, because it shows you the code of .NET 4.5 (above the code window is a pulldown menu where you can switch between the target frameworks).

That being said, you have two choices:

1. **You want to target only .NET 4.5**

   In this case, you just delete the `dnxcore50` moniker from your frameworks section of the project.json file (`net451` too because it's for class libraries only). This will turn your project an ASP.NET Core project which targets only the full .NET 4.5.
2. **You want/need to target .NET Core w/o working against the full .NET 4.5 Framework**

   This is a bit more difficult. You either need a replacement for the same library in .NET Core. If it uses the same namespaces, just add its references to the `dnxcore50` moniker and you are good to go.

   If there is no direct replacement, you have to remove this code parts from .NET Core projects, by using preprocessor directives.

   ```
   #if DNX451
   using System.DirectoryServices;
   using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
   #endif
   ```

Now your namespace will be used only in the .NET 4.5 target, but not in the .NET Core target.

**On a sidenote:** You can remove the `net451` moniker, as it's only used for Class Library (Package), the new project type for .NET Core libraries which compiles into a package which targets multiple framework targets. See the RC1 [announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/98) for more.

For applications (ASP.NET Core Web Project or xUnit project) always use the application moniker (`dnx451` and `dnxcore50` respectively). For class libraries it's `net451` and `dotnet5.x`.

Comment: Great answer, thank you.  It worked and the reason for the issue makes a lot more sense to me now.

Comment: @Tseng So if I create a new ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC6 webapp right now and need something like System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement but additionally need the entire web app to target Core 1.0 is this possible at this time with RC1?

Comment: @BlakeRivell: If you have at least one dependency which doesn't  work with .NET Core you'll have to either use ASP.NET Core with full .NET Framework (4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2 or 4.6 - or mono on linux & mac) or look for an alternative that works with .NET Core

Answer (score 0):

To the anser of @Tseng I want to add that Directory Services are planned for .NET Core 1.2. Here is the feature request on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089. You can subscribe there and get notifications when something is happening there!

When it's released you can just use Directory Services in ASP.NET Core with .NET Core! It might take some time, considering the current state and version of .NET Core, though.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has released pre-release version for System.DirectoryServices in asp.net core 2.0. You can get it from nuget package manager using this command:

Install-Package System.DirectoryServices -Version 4.5.0-preview1-25914-04

This is working fine for me till now.