# Class library references on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I've added a new Class Library (Package) project to my solution. It's my first experience with a .NET Core (or whatever I'm using, still confused)

My class library contains two references: .NET Framework 4.5.1 and .NET Platform 5.4

I'm trying to import some code from a sample project that uses `IPrincipal`. For some reason it's saying that it doesn't exist on namespace "System.Security" altohugh I can get it trough intellisense.

What's wrong with my project settings?

Comment: There is a `System.Security.Principal´ package for NET Core project (dotnet5.4)? Did you reference it in your .NET Core project? The 4.5.1 gets it from the full framework, but .NET Core is heavily modularized

Comment: This is the nuget feed of the stable release https://www.myget.org/gallery/aspnetmaster (but they should also be available via official nuget feed for rc1)

Comment: @Tseng: Probably I have to read more about this, unfortunately there is a lot of new things and It's hard to catch up quickly. It's confusing that on code editor everything seems to be well referenced and itellisense Works, just compilation fails

Comment: It's because of Class Library (Package) targets multiple frameworks, where classical Class Libraries target one framework and PCL only targets a subset for all supported frameworks. In the code editor you have a Pulldown menu on top left, where you can switch between the frameworks, then the errors of the other frameworks will be displayed and intellisense fitted to this target frameworks support. Also, you can see in the autocompletition suggestions if a method is supported in .NET Core or not

Comment: @Tseng: if you make your last comment and answer, I'll mark my question as resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new feature of .NET Core and Class Library (Package) is that it targets multiple platform and will compile into multiple assemblies which get automatically packaged into a nuget package.

When your class library targets multiple targets, it will compile to all of them. So if a certain library is only available on full .NET framework but not on .NET Core or other target framework, then you may receive intellisense if your editor is set to .NET 4.5. More information can be found in my other recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36049324/455493).

You can switch back and forth with the pull down menu on top left of the coding window, show in the screenshot below.

[image]

If you do not want to target a certain framework, you have to remove it's moniker from the project.json file or use preprocessor directives to write platform specific code or libraries/replacements.

.NET Core is heavily modularized and most of only the core modules are referenced in the default project and if you need additional one you need to reference them within the `dotnet5.x` section.

Basically you have multiple places with "dependencies" in your project.json, a global one where you can add dependencies which are available on all targeted frameworks and one within each "frameworks" section for each of the targets only.

Answer (score 1):

Though the other answer covers some basic concepts, it would require some attention on which classes are available and which are not.

Microsoft temporarily host a web site at http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net to assist.

If you can find a suitable package for RC1 from there, then you can add it to your project.json file. If not, you will have to conditional compile it to a desktop profile or use other alternatives.