# How to get Active Directory current user Display Name in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using `C# ASP.NET Core (MVC 6)` against an `on-prem Active Directory` setup. I can get the current user's `username` simply by

```
public MyModel(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    string userName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Which gives me "DOMAIN\jsmith" However, I need to get at the `Display Name`, i.e. "John Smith". How do I do this?

**Update**: After more digging, this does not seem to be currently available: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089

Comment: You could ws-federate with an identity provider like the ADFS or the Identity Server that could just return you claims, including the display name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Novell ldap library has been [ported](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard) to .NET Core. As Display Name is an [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you should be able to use the library to query for it (although there's no specific sample)

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a connection to Active Directory, find user by it's sAMAccountName attribute and query it's displayName attribute.

```
var domain = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\').First();
var accountName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\').Last();

using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{domain}"))
{
    using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
    {
        searcher.Filter = $"(sAMAccountName={name})";
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
        var searchResult = searcher.FindOne();

        if (searchResult != null && searchResult.Properties.Contains("displayName"))
        {
            var displayName = searchResult.Properties["displayName"][0];
        }
        else
        {
            // user not found
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And this is `ASP.NET Core (MVC 6)` compatible? Unless I am using the wrong package, `DirectoryEntry` does not work in a `using` because it does not implement `IDisposible`, I can not even find a reference for `DirectorySearcher` that is `ASP.NET Core` compatible.

Comment: Sorry, totally missed that. Thought you just include System.DirectoryServices dll in your project. But that is not how it works. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048910/problems-with-directory-services-and-account-management-in-asp-net-core. If this does not help, one extreme way is to move the code to a separate process, then start process and get the result via file\ process default output redirection\IPC, etc. (which method is supported in ASP.NET core)

Comment: No those namespaces don't exist in Core. Yet.

Comment: @oldovets (or anyone else for that matter) Unfortunately, in Core 1.1 they're back to .csproj files and apparently you can't simply reference GAC libs anymore.

Comment: This works if you install System.DirectoryServices Nuget package.

Answer (score -2):

Had the same issue. After some research and browsing the Microsoft Docs, I found the solution.

First install the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement package using Nuget Package Manager.

Then while calling the GetUserNameWithoutDomain method pass the following as the parameters:

`GetUserNameWithoutDomain(UserPrincipal.Current.GivenName, UserPrincipal.Current.Surname);`